# Are there model 3D surfaces with star and monstar umbilical points?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, singularity

The [Wikipedia article on umbilical points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbilical_point) classifies umbilical singularities into three types ─ star, monstar, and lemon ─ depending on the index of the singularity and the configuration of the lines of curvature around the singularity,

> [image]

and it also provides a nicely visualizable 3D model of the 'lemon' type of curvature singularity, in the form of the lines of curvature of an ellipsoid:

> [image]

I would like to have a similar understanding of the behaviour of the lines of curvature around the star and monstar umbilical points, through a specific 2D surface embedded in real 3D space. (This is with a view to making 3D printable models of the three so I can examine them in person to help with the visualization.)

What are clean ways to get such models?

Comment: I can't say this with complete certainty, but I'll bet that the "star" pattern arises in the case of the monkey-saddle.

Comment: @JohnHughes Yeah, I can imagine. I'm primarily interested in understanding the difference between the lemon and the monstar, but I'd like the set.